# microsoft report exception the definition of the report is invalid and access to .dll is denied

Tags: c#, wpf, rdlc, microsoft-reporting

I have a wpf app and I am using Microsoft Report..Everything worked fine,but all of sudden when I try to generate a report an error is thrown.
If I try to generate a report again,it works just fine.
How can I remove that error?
I get this:
[image]

EDIT: This happens only on my machine,where I developed the app.When I use it on another machine,I don't get this error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why,but after I restarted my computer,everything was back to normal...